# Custom post type menu in admin with CPT+term as submenus

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages, taxonomy-terms

I am trying to create a menu for a CPT. Requirements:

1. (SOLVED)Create menu without link. So far I used the slug for the menú javascript:void()with the key "registro-digital". That prevents link to anywhere from created menu and ensures an unique slug:

```
add_menu_page(
        __( 'Registro digital', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        __( 'Registro digital', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        'administrator',
        'javascript:void("peslam-registro-digital")',
        '',
        'dashicons-media-document',
        1
    );
```

2. (UNSOLVED, HELP!!)Do not show the submenu created automatically "Registro digital" I tried "remove_submenu_page" with no luck since the parent and the submenu are the same...Result should be:

[image: menu view]

3. (UNSOLVED, HELP!!) In the submenus are shown the CTP wit "entrada" term and the CPT with "salida" term. Everything looks ok until you try to search o filter and the filter and the search return the result for the CPT without the term filtering. The code used to create them:

```
 add_submenu_page(
        'javascript:void("peslam-registro-digital")',
        __( 'Entradas', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        __( 'Entradas', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        'administrator',
        'edit.php?&post_type=registro_digital&tipo_registro=entrada'
    );

    add_submenu_page(
        'javascript:void("peslam-registro-digital")',
        __( 'Salidas', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        __( 'Salidas', 'peslam_cecr' ),
        'administrator',
        'edit.php?&post_type=registro_digital&tipo_registro=salida'
    );
```

EXAMPLE: The URL for the entry "entrada" is "edit.php?&post_type=registro_digital&tipo_registro=salida", but if I search the URL goes to the search without "&tipo_registro=salida" what is all the point!!

Any ideas?? Thanks very much!!!

**UPDATE 1**

For number 3 I found a workaround catching the request URI when coming from "entradas" o "salidas" page, adding query var and redirecting:

```
function redireccion_registros_correcta( $query ) {
    if( !is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }

    global $pagenow;
    global $typenow;

    if ( $pagenow == "edit.php" && $typenow == "registro_digital" ){

        //URL de procedencia
        $url_parse = wp_parse_url( $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] );
        wp_parse_str( $url_parse['query'], $parameters_query ); //Almacenamos los parámetros de la query en el array $parameters_query

        //URL de destino
        $es_url_correcta = get_query_var('tipo_registro'); //Si la URL destino tiene esa query_var

        if (in_array('entrada', $parameters_query) && !$es_url_correcta) {
            $url_corrected = add_query_arg( ['tipo_registro' => 'entrada'] );
            if ( wp_redirect( $url_corrected ) ) {
                exit;
            }
        } else if (in_array('salida', $parameters_query)) {
            $url_corrected = add_query_arg( ['tipo_registro' => 'salida'] );
            if ( wp_redirect( $url_corrected ) ) {
                exit;
            }
        }
        return;
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'redireccion_registros_correcta' );
```

**Still need help with number 2, though!** (make dissappear submenu for main menu) And honestly all this look a bit "dirty" I would appreciate other approaches for the whole.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have registered your CPT. If you have done using `register_post_type( 'registro_digital', $args );` you have some options to show it in the admin menu without the need of using `add_menu_page`. These are some relevant options regarding accessing your CPT in the admin area:

```
        $args   = array(
            'label'               => __( 'Registro digital', 'registro_digital' ),
            ...
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'menu_position'       => 5,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-media-document',
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            ...
            'taxonomies'          => array( 'tipo_registro' ),

        );
        register_post_type( 'registro_digital', $args );
```

Using these parameters will show your CPT in the admin menu without duplicating it. Complete list of options here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Regarding term links I'm not sure what's exactly happening but if you attach the `taxonomies` parameter as shown above it will show a "Tipo de registro' sub menu. From this sub menu you can easily navigate filtering posts with different terms.

You could attach the taxonomy to the custom post type you have registered this way:

```
        $args   = array(
            ...
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'show_admin_column' => true,
            ...
        );
        register_taxonomy( 'tipo_registro', array( 'registro_digital' ), $args );
```

More info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/

Also I guess if you are making a typo including `?&` together in your links. And as advice 3rd parameter of `add_menu_page()` and 4th parameter of `add_submenu_page()` are capabilities, not roles. So you'd better use `manage_options` instead of `administrator`. Using roles may work but it could lead in troubles in future releases.

Best regards.

Comment: thx for the quick answer. I registered the CPT and taxonomy that way and I tried adding that options but the result is the menu+submenu (still duplicated) and no submenus for taxonomies (Registro digital - Registro digital / Add new) :-(

Comment: Did you removed the add_menu_page() and add_submenu_page()?

Comment: Yes, I did it again just in case and doesn't work :-(